# To tag or not to tag, what's the limiting behavior of this simple game?

Tags: probability, game-theory

$N$ players are playing paintball tag. They stand in a circle and take turns clockwise to act, starting from player 1, as illustrated below. The last untagged participant wins

[image]

The rules are simple. In his turn, a player can either randomly tag one of the other players, or shoot in the air. But if nobody is tagged in a whole round (i.e. all players have chosen to shoot in the air their last turn), the referee will randomly pick one player as the winner. Players act to maximize their own winning probabilities, but prefer shooting in the air to tagging if both are equally good.

For sufficiently large $N$, will player 1 always choose to tag at the start of the game?

---

Notice that if it's optimal for player 1 to shoot in the air at the start of the $N-1$ game, then it'll be optimal for them to tag at the start of the $N$ game. So for large $N$, tagging will happen at least as frequently as shooting in the air at the start of the game.

Comment: An interesting variant, harder I think, is if you allow players to choose their victim (but randomly for choices which result in the same probability of survival).

Comment: @quasi It doesn't matter. If they decide to shoot, anyone is as good. They will randomize between all other players. So your variant is exactly the same as this one.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, for $n > 3$, the choice of who to tag (if allowed) _does_ matter.

Comment: @quasi No, it doesn't. Tag anyone you want in the $n$ game, you're always going to be the last to shoot in the $n-1$ game.

Comment: Doesn't player $1$ start every round (assuming player $1$ is still alive)? More generally, for each new round, doesn't it start with the lowest numbered player who is still alive?

Comment: @quasi Suppose $n=4$ and player 1 shoots player 2. Now 2 is out of the game. We have players 1,3,4, and it's now player 3's turn to act. Player 3 will of course shoot in the air, so does 4 and 1 after him. Now three players alive have all choose to skip their turn, referee comes in and choose a winner. Same thing happens had player 1 shoots 3 or 4 instead.

Comment: Oh, I misread the rules: I thought the referee chooses one player to _eliminate_, after which a new round starts.

Comment: In any case, nice problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strange game.

For $n=2$, obviously tag and win. For $n=3$, tag and the third player tags you back, the classic standoff. Referee-selection happens, everyone wins with probability $1/3$.

For $n>3$, suppose not tagging is correct. Then it is equally correct for everyone, and referee-selection happens - everyone wins with probability $1/n$.

However, suppose you do tag, and further suppose tagging is correct until it reaches $3\leq m$ standoffs. The standoffs each win with probability $1/m$, so what's the probability of being one of them?

Since *you can't tag yourself*, after the first turn there are $n-1$ players, you guaranteed to be one of them. Everyone after that point will be tagging until $m$ standoffs, and since $n-m<n$, you won't get a chance to tag again (all the player-tags will have happened).

Whoever's next fires, with $n-2$ targets, so you dodge that paint with probability $(n-3)/(n-2)$. The person after that aims at $n-3$ targets and you dodge *that* with probability $(n-4)/(n-3)$. The last tag occurs with $m$ targets (from $m+1$, to leave $m$ standing). You make it through to the last $m$ with probability
$$\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-4}{n-3}\dotsm\frac{m}{m+1}\frac{m-1}{m}=\frac{m-1}{n-2}$$
and counting final jeopardy, that gives a winrate when tagging of
$$\frac{m-1}{m(n-2)}\text{.}$$

To not tag, you want
$$\frac{m-1}{m(n-2)}\leq\frac{1}{n}\quad\Rightarrow\quad n\geq2m$$
where $m$ was the last standoff population size, which means you refuse to tag at $n=3\cdot2^k$. Therefore, there's no berzerker population limit.

Comment: I don't understand you analysis for the case $n=3$. I agree that for $n=3$, all players should shoot in the air, but it seems to me that in the continuation, player $3$ can never survive, and the survival probabilities for players $1$ and $2$ are $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ respectively.

Comment: Did a moderator just delete all the comments?

Comment: Don't know -- I just got here.

Comment: Ignore my initial comment. I misread the rules. I thought in the case of a round with no tagging, the referee randomly chooses one player to eliminate, after which a new round starts and the game continues until only one player is left. With that rule change, the analysis is harder. I think.

Comment: @obscurans I wonder, if the players prefer tagging to shooting in the air, will the result be much different? It seems things will go against their wishes, i.e. tagging will become rarer and shooting in the air more common. I don't know if shooting in the air will still be exponentially rarer than tagging.

Comment: @quasi I see your point. I think that case will indeed be much more difficult. Players' behaviors will be more chaotic perhaps.

Comment: @Eric: For that variant, my first comment to the accepted answer is valid. Also, for $n=4$ (with the same variant),  the first player should tag randomly, after which, for that round, the remaining players should shoot in the air.

Comment: There's a serious flaw: "since $n-m\lt n$, you won't get a chance to tag again (all the player-tags will have happened)." This is wrong because tagged players are removed and don't get a chance to tag, so the right hand side of the inequality is some variable smaller than $n$. You may very well get a chance to tag again before m is reached. For example, if everyone tags someone behind themselves, you get your chance to tag again after $(n-1)/2$ players finish their turns!